# Why can't I get past the credentials page when running Grafana in ECS?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, grafana, fargate

I have been playing for a while with Grafana, installed in Docker on my Mac. That's been working great.  My company has a set of Terraform code that lets one easily host an arbitrary Docker image/container under AWS ECS Fargate.  I just used this code to deploy the `grafana/grafana-enterprise` Docker image from Docker Hub into ECS.

With either version, hitting the root endpoint presents me with a login dialog.  I enter "admin" and "admin" and press the "Log In" button.  Then I press "Skip" to skip changing the password to something more secure.

When Grafana is running on my Mac, I then get the initial dashboard display.  When running in ECS, I am again presented with the credentials dialog.  If I go ahead and supply a new password for the admin user, I'm still taken back to the original login prompt.  So I'm in an infinite GUI loop and can't log into Grafana.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?  I can find nothing of note in the documentation for the Docker image.  I am not specifying any volumes or environment variables, and I've defined the standard port mapping of 3000 -> 3000 in my ECS task definition.

ADDED NOTE: When I press "Log In", a temporary flag is displayed and then disappears that says "Logged In".

Comment: this seems like an issue with session/cookies, check the settings of the load balancers, maybe enable sticky sessions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html

Comment: @ralz  Damn.  I though that would be it.  It makes perfect sense.  But alas, turning on "group level stickiness" on the ALB doesn't change the behavior :(. Thanks for the thought.

Comment: @ralz - That IS It.  Your suggestion gave me a though.  If I hit one of the containers directly, using its IP, then Grafana works!  So it is something about the load balancer. So you've given me something to work with.  Thanks again.

Comment: did you try playing with stickiness type, Load balancer generated cookie/Application-based cookie.